# How can i install python modules that have spaces in between?

Tags: python

I wanted to run a script that would scan my network and that script uses a awesome library called who-is-on-my-wifi. I have installed the module to run the script but i get errors from the prompt saying that it cannot detect such a module in the system.
This is the script.

```
from who_is_on_my_wifi import *

WHO = who()
for i in range(0, len(WHO)):
    print(WHO[i])
```

And this is the error that i get.

```
python scanner.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scanner.py", line 1, in <module>
    from who_is_on_my_wifi import *
ImportError: No module named who_is_on_my_wifi
```

This is the proof that i have installed the module

```
pip3 install 'who_is_on_my_wifi'
Requirement already satisfied: who_is_on_my_wifi in /home/harein/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: getmac in /home/harein/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from who_is_on_my_wifi) (0.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-nmap in /home/harein/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from who_is_on_my_wifi) (0.6.1)
```

Any suggestions on how i can avoid this can continue executing my script ?

**EDIT**

The script finally executed the way i want by changing the,

`python scanner.py` to `python3 scanner.py`

You guys were right, it was the way how i executed the script that generated this error and it was not a problem in the module apparently.

I would like to thank everyone who gave the support.<3

Comment: could you also try with `python3 scanner.py`? it could be the default python interpreter be set to `python2` and you installed the library for `python3`.

Comment: The issue isn't the underscores. The issue is that you haven't installed the module in the place where the instance of python that you are using is searching for it.

Comment: The title is confusing. Underscores != spaces.

Comment: Possibly, you got multiple python versions installed. Install via `python -m pip install who_is_on_my_wifi`, to make sure it gets installed to version you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to

```
import this_is_not_a_module
```

the error you get:

```
ImportError: No module named this_is_not_a_module
```

is the error raised by Python 2.

Python 3 would raise a different one:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'this_is_not_a_module'
```

So, your actual problem is that your system tries to execute your script with some Python 2 version, while you installed your module for your Python 3.8 version.

Comment: I never noticed that difference between the errors in the two versions. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you can't import modules because you have installed two python versions(or conda along with it). if you have, delete one of your python versions or activate conda and try importing your module, or just try:

```
pip uninstall who_is_on_my_wifi
pip install who_is_on_my_wifi
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually tend to install modules per project and use virtualenv for it.
It kind of links respective versions of programs (like python interpreter, pip and so on) and takes care of PYTHONPATH and the way of installed dependencies.

```
$ pip3 install virtualenv
$ virtualenv whoisonwifi
$ source whoisonwifi/bin/activate
$ pip --version
```

> pip 21.0.1 from
> /mnt/devel/workonhome/whoisonwifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip
> (python 3.7)

```
$ pip install 'who_is_on_my_wifi'
```

from there your code (sort of) works for me.